# Analytical expressions for ODE integration methods using Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, ode

I am trying to use Sympy to calculate analytical expressions for the error of numerical solutions of ordinary differential equations (ODEs), such as the Euler and Runge-Kutta methods.

We have the ODE: $\dot x = f(x)$ with initial value $x(t_0) = x_0$, and we want to find the error of the approximate solution $x(t+\Delta t) \approx x_0 + \Delta t f(x_0) + \Delta t^2 f'(x_0)f(x_0)/2 +...$.

The procedure is to expand the solution $x(t)$ in a Taylor series up to two orders higher than the numerical method under analysis and then compare this expansion to the expanded evaluation of the numerical solution. For the Euler method this is very straightforward (easy), because both expansions don't require much algebra:

Euler method: x1 = x0 + \Delta t f(x_0)

Taylor series, up to $O(\Delta t^2)$: $x(t+\Delta t) = x_0 + \Delta t f(x_0) + \Delta t^2 f'(x_0)f(x_0)/2 + O(\Delta t^3) $

Error: $|E| = | \Delta t^2 f'(x_0)f(x_0)/2 | $.

The trick above is to use $dx/dt = f(x)$ and $d^2x/dt^2 = (df/dx)(dx/dt)$ (chain rule) in the Taylor expansion of $x(t)$. However, in order 2 or higher, things become more complicated, so I would like to use Sympy, to help in the development of the expressions.

Here is my attempt:

```py
from sympy import *
init_printing()

t, t0, dt, x, x0, x1, x_dot = symbols("t t_0 {\\Delta}t x x_0 x_1 \\dot{x}") 
xt, f  = symbols("x f", cls=Function) #x(t) e f(x(t))
Erro =symbols("E")
fp = [f] # A Python list to contain the symbols of df/dx, up to order 9
string_fp = "f"
for i in range(1,10):
    string_fp +="'"
    fp.append(symbols(string_fp, cls=Function))

def my_taylor(f, x, x0, order):
    Taylor_expansion = f(x0)
    for i in range(1, order+1):
        Taylor_expansion += (1/factorial(i))*((x-x0)**i)* diff(f(x), x, i)
        #Taylor_expansion += (1/factorial(i))*((x-x0)**i)* diff(f(x), x, i).subs(x,x0)
        #Taylor_expansion += (1/factorial(i))*((x-x0)**i)*fp[i](x0)
    Taylor_expansion += Order((x-x0)**(order+1),(x,x0))
    return Taylor_expansion

#teste = my_taylor(f, x, x0, 2)

def my_other_taylor(xt, t, t0, f, order):
    Taylor_expansion = xt(t0)
    Taylor_expansion += (t-t0)*f(x0)
    for i in range(2, order+1):
        #Taylor_expansion += (1/factorial(i))*((t-t0)**i)* diff(f(x), x, i-1).subs(x,x0)
        #Taylor_expansion += (1/factorial(i))*((t-t0)**i)*fp[i](x0)
        Taylor_expansion += (1/factorial(i))*((t-t0)**i)* diff(f(xt(t)), t, i-1).subs(xt(t),x0)
    #Taylor_expansion += Order((factor(t-t0)**(order+1)))
    Taylor_expansion += Order((t-t0)**(order+1),(t,t0))
    return Taylor_expansion
#teste2 = my_other_taylor(xt, t, t0, f, 5)

#Taylor_f  = f(x).series(x, x0=x0, n=3)
#Taylor_x  = xt(t).series(t, x0=t0, n=3)
#Taylor_x_2 = Taylor_x.subs(diff(xt(t),t), f(x))  ## Esta substituição não está funcionando
Taylor_f = my_taylor(f, x, x0, 2)
Taylor_x = my_other_taylor(xt, t, t0, f, 4)
Taylor_x_dt = Taylor_x.subs(t, dt+t0)

#Taylor_x_2 = Taylor_x.subs(t-t0, dt)
pprint(Taylor_x_dt, use_unicode=True)

### Calcular x1 usando método de Euler
x1 = x0 + dt*f(x0)
Erro = abs(x1-Taylor_x_dt.removeO().subs(xt(t0),x0))
```

I am not getting the correct results, and I can see why, but I don't know how to fix the Taylor expansion. The derivatives of $f(x)$ are supposed to be "evaluated" at $x_0$, but I can't find how to make a symbolic evaluation of a derivative in sympy's documentation and tutorials. If I make `.subs(x, x0)`, it substitutes the variable used in the differentiation  , like $df(x)/dx$ becomes $df(x_0)/dx_0$, instead of $df(x_0)/dx$. Also, I can't find a way to apply the chain rule and substitute the time derivatives of $x(t)$ by the derivatives of $f$ w.r.t $x$.

Comment: So your question is strictly about getting the Taylor expansion of the local truncation error? // And yes, when displaying a derivative the current symbol is taken for the denominator, this was already remarked multiple times. Internally only the information about the derivative order (and probably the argument positions) is stored. It would be difficult to invent a mechanism that consistently assigns variable names for the fraction format, so the easiest method is to take the actual current argument names.

Comment: Yes, I am satisfied in using Sympy to get the Taylor expansion of the local truncation error. A bonus would be to learn how to express derivatives taken on a specified point, as it happens in series expansion sometimes, but I don't care about it too much, as long as we can express things correctly. Thanks for your interest and help.

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare the Taylor expansions in `h` of `x(t+h)`, a solution to `x'(t)=f(x(t))` and `stepper(f,t,x(t),h)` to get the truncation error of the method implemented in `stepper`. For higher order methods one would use B-series based on rooted trees to represent the compositions of derivatives of `f`.

The easiest approach to implement this is to implement `f(x+dx)` as polynomial or truncated Taylor series in a procedure

```
import sympy as sy
sy.init_printing()

x,h = sy.symbols("x h")
f = sy.symbols("f_{:20}", commutative=False)

def eval_f(y,n):
    res = f[n]
    dx = y-x
    for k in range(n):
        res = res/(n-k)*dx+f[n-1-k]
    return res
```

Then the exact solution can be found via Picard iteration, which is a slow process

```
xe = x+sy.Order(h,h);
for k in range(5):
    Dxe = eval_f(xe,k+1)
    xe = x+sy.integrate(Dxe,h)
    print("\nexact ",k,": ",xe.expand().simplify())
```

which has output

```
exact  0 :  x + h*f_{0} + O(h**2)

exact  1 :  x + h*f_{0} + h**2*f_{1}*f_{0}/2 + O(h**3)

exact  2 :  x + h*f_{0} + h**2*f_{1}*f_{0}/2 + h**3*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/6 + h**3*f_{1}**2*f_{0}/6 + O(h**4)

exact  3 :  x + h*f_{0} + h**2*f_{1}*f_{0}/2 + h**3*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/6 + h**3*f_{1}**2*f_{0}/6 + h**4*f_{3}*f_{0}**3/24 + h**4*f_{2}*f_{1}*f_{0}**2/16 + h**4*f_{2}*f_{0}*f_{1}*f_{0}/16 + h**4*f_{1}**3*f_{0}/24 + h**4*f_{1}*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/24 + O(h**5)

exact  4 :  x + h*f_{0} + h**2*f_{1}*f_{0}/2 + h**3*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/6 + h**3*f_{1}**2*f_{0}/6 + h**4*f_{3}*f_{0}**3/24 + h**4*f_{2}*f_{1}*f_{0}**2/16 + h**4*f_{2}*f_{0}*f_{1}*f_{0}/16 + h**4*f_{1}**3*f_{0}/24 + h**4*f_{1}*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/24 + h**5*f_{4}*f_{0}**4/120 + h**5*f_{3}*f_{1}*f_{0}**3/60 + h**5*f_{3}*f_{0}**2*f_{1}*f_{0}/60 + h**5*f_{3}*f_{0}*f_{1}*f_{0}**2/60 + h**5*f_{2}**2*f_{0}**3/60 + h**5*f_{2}*(f_{1}*f_{0})**2/40 + h**5*f_{2}*f_{1}**2*f_{0}**2/60 + h**5*f_{2}*f_{0}*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/60 + h**5*f_{2}*f_{0}*f_{1}**2*f_{0}/60 + h**5*f_{1}**4*f_{0}/120 + h**5*f_{1}**2*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/120 + h**5*f_{1}*f_{3}*f_{0}**3/120 + h**5*f_{1}*f_{2}*f_{1}*f_{0}**2/80 + h**5*f_{1}*f_{2}*f_{0}*f_{1}*f_{0}/80 + O(h**6)
```

Now one can implement the usual numerical methods, like the second order Heun method

```
k1 = eval_f(x,0)  
k2 = eval_f(x+h*k1,3)  +sy.Order(h**3,h);
xheun = x+((k1+k2)*h/2).expand()
print("Heun: ", xheun)
print("error: ", xheun-xe)
```

with result

```
Heun:  x + h*f_{0} + h**2*f_{1}*f_{0}/2 + h**3*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/4 + O(h**4)
error:  h**3*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/12 - h**3*f_{1}**2*f_{0}/6 + O(h**4)
```

or the second order explicit midpoint method

```
k1 = eval_f(x,0)  
k2 = eval_f(x+h*k1,3)  +sy.Order(h**3,h);
xheun = x+((k1+k2)*h/2).expand()
print("Heun: ", xheun)
print("error: ", xheun-xe)

print()
k2 = eval_f(x+k1*h/2,3)+sy.Order(h**3,h);
xmid = x+(k2*h).expand()
xmid = xmid.expand()
print("midpoint: ", xmid)
print("error: ", xmid-xe)
```

with result

```
midpoint:  x + h*f_{0} + h**2*f_{1}*f_{0}/2 + h**3*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/8 + O(h**4)
error:  -h**3*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/24 - h**3*f_{1}**2*f_{0}/6 + O(h**4)
```

And finally, the standard RK4 method

```
k2 = eval_f(x+k1*h/2,4).expand()  +sy.Order(h**5,h);
k3 = eval_f(x+k2*h/2,4).expand()  +sy.Order(h**5,h);
k4 = eval_f(x+k3*h  ,4).expand()  +sy.Order(h**5,h);

xrk4 = x+((k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)*h/6).expand()
print("\nRK4:")
print("k1 = ",k1)
print("k2 = ",k2)
print("k3 = ",k3)
print("k4 = ",k4)
print("\nxRK4 = ",xrk4)
print("error = ",(xrk4-xe))
```

with output

```
k1 =  f_{0}

k2 =  f_{0} + h*f_{1}*f_{0}/2 + h**2*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/8 + h**3*f_{3}*f_{0}**3/48 + h**4*f_{4}*f_{0}**4/384 + O(h**5)

k3 =  f_{0} + h*f_{1}*f_{0}/2 + h**2*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/8 + h**2*f_{1}**2*f_{0}/4 + h**3*f_{3}*f_{0}**3/48 + h**3*f_{2}*f_{1}*f_{0}**2/16 + h**3*f_{2}*f_{0}*f_{1}*f_{0}/16 + h**3*f_{1}*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/16 + h**4*f_{4}*f_{0}**4/384 + h**4*f_{3}*f_{1}*f_{0}**3/96 + h**4*f_{3}*f_{0}**2*f_{1}*f_{0}/96 + h**4*f_{3}*f_{0}*f_{1}*f_{0}**2/96 + h**4*f_{2}**2*f_{0}**3/64 + h**4*f_{2}*f_{1}*f_{0}*f_{1}*f_{0}/32 + h**4*f_{2}*f_{0}*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/64 + h**4*f_{1}*f_{3}*f_{0}**3/96 + O(h**5)

k4 =  f_{0} + h*f_{1}*f_{0} + h**2*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/2 + h**2*f_{1}**2*f_{0}/2 + h**3*f_{3}*f_{0}**3/6 + h**3*f_{2}*f_{1}*f_{0}**2/4 + h**3*f_{2}*f_{0}*f_{1}*f_{0}/4 + h**3*f_{1}**3*f_{0}/4 + h**3*f_{1}*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/8 + h**4*f_{4}*f_{0}**4/24 + h**4*f_{3}*f_{1}*f_{0}**3/12 + h**4*f_{3}*f_{0}**2*f_{1}*f_{0}/12 + h**4*f_{3}*f_{0}*f_{1}*f_{0}**2/12 + h**4*f_{2}**2*f_{0}**3/16 + h**4*f_{2}*f_{1}**2*f_{0}**2/8 + h**4*f_{2}*f_{1}*f_{0}*f_{1}*f_{0}/8 + h**4*f_{2}*f_{0}*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/16 + h**4*f_{2}*f_{0}*f_{1}**2*f_{0}/8 + h**4*f_{1}**2*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/16 + h**4*f_{1}*f_{3}*f_{0}**3/48 + h**4*f_{1}*f_{2}*f_{1}*f_{0}**2/16 + h**4*f_{1}*f_{2}*f_{0}*f_{1}*f_{0}/16 + O(h**5)


xRK4 =  x + h*f_{0} + h**2*f_{1}*f_{0}/2 + h**3*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/6 + h**3*f_{1}**2*f_{0}/6 + h**4*f_{3}*f_{0}**3/24 + h**4*f_{2}*f_{1}*f_{0}**2/16 + h**4*f_{2}*f_{0}*f_{1}*f_{0}/16 + h**4*f_{1}**3*f_{0}/24 + h**4*f_{1}*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/24 + 5*h**5*f_{4}*f_{0}**4/576 + 5*h**5*f_{3}*f_{1}*f_{0}**3/288 + 5*h**5*f_{3}*f_{0}**2*f_{1}*f_{0}/288 + 5*h**5*f_{3}*f_{0}*f_{1}*f_{0}**2/288 + h**5*f_{2}**2*f_{0}**3/64 + h**5*f_{2}*f_{1}**2*f_{0}**2/48 + h**5*f_{2}*f_{1}*f_{0}*f_{1}*f_{0}/32 + h**5*f_{2}*f_{0}*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/64 + h**5*f_{2}*f_{0}*f_{1}**2*f_{0}/48 + h**5*f_{1}**2*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/96 + h**5*f_{1}*f_{3}*f_{0}**3/144 + h**5*f_{1}*f_{2}*f_{1}*f_{0}**2/96 + h**5*f_{1}*f_{2}*f_{0}*f_{1}*f_{0}/96 + O(h**6)

error =  h**5*f_{4}*f_{0}**4/2880 + h**5*f_{3}*f_{1}*f_{0}**3/1440 + h**5*f_{3}*f_{0}**2*f_{1}*f_{0}/1440 + h**5*f_{3}*f_{0}*f_{1}*f_{0}**2/1440 - h**5*f_{2}**2*f_{0}**3/960 - h**5*f_{2}*(f_{1}*f_{0})**2/40 + h**5*f_{2}*f_{1}**2*f_{0}**2/240 + h**5*f_{2}*f_{1}*f_{0}*f_{1}*f_{0}/32 - h**5*f_{2}*f_{0}*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/960 + h**5*f_{2}*f_{0}*f_{1}**2*f_{0}/240 - h**5*f_{1}**4*f_{0}/120 + h**5*f_{1}**2*f_{2}*f_{0}**2/480 - h**5*f_{1}*f_{3}*f_{0}**3/720 - h**5*f_{1}*f_{2}*f_{1}*f_{0}**2/480 - h**5*f_{1}*f_{2}*f_{0}*f_{1}*f_{0}/480 + O(h**6)
```

With this last leading error term one can start to see the limitations of this approach. While setting the derivatives `f` to "commutative" would combine some term, it would combine too many of them. Setting them non-commutative leaves some terms separate that are really the same as the derivatives of a vector-valued system function are symmetric in their vector arguments. Thus the need to introduce special algebraic types that would strictly follow these rules.